# How to define an operator like ⊕？

Tags: functions, operators, algebra

For example, I define the circle plus as

```
a_\[CirclePlus]b_ := a + b^2;
a__\[CirclePlus]b_ := (a[[1 ;;-2]]\[CirclePlus]a[[-1]])\[CirclePlus]b;
```

But when I try

```
a\[CirclePlus]b\[CirclePlus]c
```

it does not work.

I would like it translated as

```
a\[CirclePlus]b\[CirclePlus]c = (a\[CirclePlus]b) \[CirclePlus]c
```

or more generally

```
a_1\[CirclePlus] ... \[CirclePlus]a_[n-1]\[CirclePlus]a_n = (a_1\[CirclePlus] ... \[CirclePlus]a_[n-1]) \[CirclePlus]a_n
```

Comment: You should be able to do `Attributes[CirclePlus]=Flat`, and then your first definition should do the trick

Comment: Why not use CircleMinus instead? It already has left grouping.

Comment: @CarlWoll That's strange. Why should `CircleMinus` be automatically left-associative but `CirclePlus` not? Who made that choice and why? Is it just to make it more consistent with `Subtract`, which is non-associative and therefore requires a choice or left or right associativity by default?

Comment: @
Lukas Lang 
Now I try
``` 
Clear[CircleDot, CirclePlus, CircleMinus, CircleTimes];
a_\[CirclePlus]b_ := a + b^2;
Attributes[CirclePlus] = Flat; 
```
 But it gave
```
CirclePlus[a]+(CirclePlus[b]+CirclePlus[c]^2)^2
```

Comment: @CarlWoll Yes, the `CircleMinus` works. However I need to define more than two different operators. So I need to fix it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want [CirclePlus] to be left associative, you have to specify it like e.g.:

```
ClearAll["Globals`*"]
a_ ⊕ b_ ⊕ c__ = (a ⊕ b)⊕ c;
```

then:

```
a ⊕ b ⊕ c
(* (a⊕b)⊕c *)
```

And when you want to give ⊕ some meaning you could e.g. in addition write:

```
a_ ⊕ b_ = a + b^2;
```

then:

```
a ⊕ b ⊕ c
(* a + b^2 + c^2 *)
```

Comment: But what if I want to calculate `a\[CirclePlus]b\[CirclePlus]c\[CirclePlus]d` or even more variables?

Comment: Why you do not try it out? Note that c__ has 2 blanks

Comment: Thanks @Daniel! I overlooked the 2 blanks! I still have one question: why `a__\[CirclePlus]b_ := (a[[1 ;;-2]]\[CirclePlus]a[[-1]])\[CirclePlus]b;` doesn't work?

Comment: This leads to an infinite recursion. with: (a[[1 ;;-2]]\[CirclePlus]a[[-1]]) evaluated over and over.

Comment: Thanks. It seems the problem is the indexing [[ ]] due to a__ is CirclePlus[...] and cannot be indexed.